# CSS3 Flip effect with variable size content

Tags: variables, css, size, flip

I've read some tutorials about making a flip effect on a block element using CSS3 properties, and tried to reproduce it.

My problem is that, in each of these tutorials, all the "flippers" had a fixed size, and I would like to make on with a variable size, depending on it's content.

Here is the code i have :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style type="text/css">
        html * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        /*===============================================*/
        /* FLIPPER REQUIRED CSS                          */
        /*===============================================*/
        .Flipper
        {
            position: relative;
            /*overflow: auto;/**/

            -webkit-perspective: 600px;
               -moz-perspective: 600px;
                -ms-perspective: 600px;
                 -o-perspective: 600px;
                    perspective: 600px;
        }
        .Flipper > .Content
        {
            position: absolute;
            /*overflow: auto;/**/
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;

            -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg);
               -moz-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                 -o-transform: rotateX(0deg);
                    transform: rotateX(0deg);

            -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
               -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                 -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
                    transform-style: preserve-3d;

            -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
               -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                 -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
                    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
        }
        .Flipper:hover > .Content, .Flipper .Back
        {
            -webkit-transform: rotateX(180deg);
               -moz-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                -ms-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                 -o-transform: rotateX(180deg);
                    transform: rotateX(180deg);
        }
        .Flipper .Front, .Flipper .Back
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            /*overflow: auto;/**/

            -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
               -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
                -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
                 -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
                    backface-visibility: hidden;
        }
        /*===============================================*/
        /* FLIPPER CUSTOM CSS                            */
        /*===============================================*/   
        .Flipper
        {
            /*
            width: 400px;
            height: 400px;
            */
        }
        .Flipper {
            background: #00F;
        }
        .Flipper .Front {
            background: #0F0;
        }
        .Flipper .Back {
            background: #F00;
        }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="Flipper">
            <div class="Content">
                <div class="Front">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
                <div class="Back">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If i provide a fixed width and height (or min width and min height) for the .Flipper elements, it works fine, but if i don't, the flipper doesn't appear.

I supposed it is because everyone is positioned in absolute. So i tried to use : overflow: auto; on every block that contained a absolute-positioned element, but it did not help. I then tried to remove all the width: 100%; and height: 100%; and use the overflow: auto; but i got the same result.
Do you know anyway to make the .Flipper elements fit the size of the contents of .Front and .Back elements ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is a jsfiddle of the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/x7rKy/ The above works fine for me.